# can you spot the nil while unwrapping?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, firebase

I'm trying to find where is the nil when unwrapping. Here is the piece of code I have. The lines where the fatal errors are found are at:

1st file:

```
date = dateFormatter().date(from: dictionary[kDATE] as! String)!
```

2nd file:

```
self.allLists.append(ShoppingList.init(dictionary: currentList))
```

This is from the shoppingList.swift file and the function is called in a controller

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class ShoppingList{
    let name: String
    var totalPrice: Float
    var totalItems: Int
    var id: String
    var date: Date
    var ownerId: String

    init(_name: String, _totalPrice: Float = 0, _id: String = "") {
        name = _name
        totalPrice = _totalPrice
        totalItems = 0
        id = _id
        date = Date()
        ownerId = "1234"
    }

    //creates shopping list item from this dictionary

    init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

        name = dictionary[kNAME] as! String
        totalPrice = dictionary[kTOTALPRICE] as! Float
        totalItems = dictionary[kTOTALITEMS] as! Int
        id = dictionary[kSHOPPINGLISTID] as! String
        date = dateFormatter().date(from: dictionary[kDATE] as! String)!
        ownerId = dictionary[kOWNERID] as! String
    }

    func dictionaryFromItem(item: ShoppingList) -> NSDictionary {

        return NSDictionary(objects: [item.name, item.totalPrice, item.totalItems, item.id, dateFormatter().string(from: item.date), item.ownerId], forKeys: [kNAME as NSCopying, kTOTALPRICE as NSCopying, kTOTALITEMS as NSCopying, kSHOPPINGLISTID as NSCopying, kDATE as NSCopying, kOWNERID as NSCopying])

    }
```

Here is the controller:

```
import UIKit
import KRProgressHUD


class AllListsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var allLists:[ShoppingList] = []
    var nameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadLists()

    }

    //MARK: TableView DataSource

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return allLists.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let shoppingList = allLists[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = shoppingList.name

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: IBActions


    @IBAction func addBarButonItemPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Create Shopping List", message: "Enter the shopping list name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addTextField{ (nameTextField) in

            nameTextField.placeholder = "Name"
            self.nameTextField = nameTextField
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel){ (action) in


        }

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default){ (action) in

            if self.nameTextField.text != ""{

                self.createShoppingList()

            }else{

                KRProgressHUD.showWarning(message: "Name is empty!")
            }

        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(saveAction)

        self.present(alertController,animated: true, completion:nil)


    }

    //MARK: LoadList


    func loadLists(){

        //.values has all the info of the child

        firebase.child(kSHOPPINGLIST).child("1234").observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in

            self.allLists.removeAll()

            //if we actually received smthing from firebase

            if snapshot.exists(){

                let sorted = ((snapshot.value as! NSDictionary).allValues as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: kDATE,ascending: false)])

                for list in sorted {

                    let currentList = list as! NSDictionary

                    self.allLists.append(ShoppingList.init(dictionary: currentList))

                }

            } else {

                print("no snapshot")
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })


    }


    //MARK: Helper functions

    func createShoppingList(){


        let shoppingList = ShoppingList(_name: nameTextField.text!)

        shoppingList.saveItemInBackground(shoppingList: shoppingList){ (error) in

            if error != nil{

                KRProgressHUD.showError(message: "Error creating shopping list")
                return

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also the data formatter is a small function in another file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

private let dateFormat = "yyyyMMDDHHmmss"

func dateFormatter() -> DateFormatter {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat

    return dateFormatter

}
```

Comment: Please post just relevant code.

Comment: And please study http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: "I'm trying to find where is the nil when unwrapping" No, you are not trying. Every exclamation mark in your code (`!`) means "please crash me". You cannot complain if that is exactly what happens. All you have to do to find the `nil` is look for it — yourself. Do not use any exclamation marks! Do all your downcasting and your unwrapping of Optionals _safely_ and step through in the debugger to see what's actually happening.

Comment: @rmaddy i thought they would be helpfull for you to understand what im doing, i also had red the question  you are reffering and i was stuck. thank you for your time commenting.

Comment: @matt i was trying to safely unwrapp the valuew inside an if but the compiler was complaining that i wasnt initializing all of the values.
thank you for your time commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a forced downcast and a forced optional unwrap on this line:

```
date = dateFormatter().date(from: dictionary[kDATE] as! String)!
```

Either your dictionary isn't returning a string, or the string coming out of the dictionary isn't able to be processed as a date. My guess is it's the first problem as dates are often stored as [epoch](https://currentmillis.com).

Try this instead of the line above. Add a breakpoint at the top and step through:

```
print(dictionary[kDATE])
if let dictValue = dictionary[kDATE] as? String {
   print(dictValue)
   if let unwrappedDate = dateFormatter().date(from: dictValue) {
       date = unwrappedDate
   }
}
```

If it fails on the first if-let then the return value is not a string. If it fails on the second the problem lies with the date formatter being unable to read the format.

The first print might give you a clue as to what type to cast to, the second could help you fix the format.

Try to be careful when force unwrapping,

```
optionalVar!
```

or for downcasting.

```
unknownType as! Type
```

You should really only "use the force" when you're absolutely sure there's no way the value will be nil.